# scala: found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel

I build a scala sbt project(marked as "example") which reference some additional projects, the sbt file is:

```
val chiselVersion = "3.6.0"
scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalacOptions ++= Seq(
    "-language:reflectiveCalls",
    "-deprecation",
    "-unchecked",
    "-feature",
    "-Xsource:2.13",
    "-Ymacro-annotations"
  ),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.6.12"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.12" % "test"),
  //addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1")
    //addCompilerPlugin(("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.1").cross(CrossVersion.full))
)

lazy val chiselSettings = Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % chiselVersion
    //"edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chiseltest" % "0.5.4"
  ),
  addCompilerPlugin(("edu.berkeley.cs" % "chisel3-plugin" % chiselVersion).cross(CrossVersion.full))
)

lazy val cde = (project in file("rocket-chip/cde/cde"))
  .settings(commonSettings)

lazy val hardfloat = (project in file("rocket-chip/hardfloat"))
  .settings(commonSettings, chiselSettings)

lazy val rocketMacros = (project in file("rocket-chip/macros"))
  .settings(commonSettings)

lazy val rocketchip = (Project("rocket-chip", file("rocket-chip/src")))
  .settings(commonSettings, chiselSettings)
  .settings(
    Compile / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value / "main" / "scala",
    Compile / resourceDirectory := baseDirectory.value / "main" / "resources"
  )
  .dependsOn(cde)
  .dependsOn(hardfloat)
  .dependsOn(rocketMacros)

lazy val example = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings, chiselSettings)
  .dependsOn(rocketchip)
  .dependsOn(cde)
```

the rocketchip is the additional project, and there are 3 subprojects in it, the sbt file of "rocketchip" is:

```
// See LICENSE.Berkeley for license details.

import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
import scala.sys.process._

enablePlugins(PackPlugin)

val chiselVersion = "3.6.0"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "edu.berkeley.cs",
  version      := "1.6.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.13.10",
  parallelExecution in Global := false,
  traceLevel   := 15,
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation","-unchecked"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "4.0.6"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0" % "test"),
  resolvers ++= Seq(
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
    Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
    Resolver.mavenLocal
  ),
  publishMavenStyle := true,
  publishArtifact in Test := false,
  pomIncludeRepository := { x => false },
  pomExtra := <url>https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache 2</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
    <license>
      <name>BSD-style</name>
        <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
      </license>
    </licenses>
    <scm>
      <url>https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocketchip.git</url>
      <connection>scm:git:github.com/chipsalliance/rocketchip.git</connection>
    </scm>,
  publishTo := {
    val v = version.value
    val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
    if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
      Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
    }
    else {
      Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
    }
  }
)

lazy val chiselSettings = Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq("edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % chiselVersion),
  addCompilerPlugin("edu.berkeley.cs" % "chisel3-plugin" % chiselVersion cross CrossVersion.full)
)

lazy val cde = (project in file("cde"))
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(publishArtifact := false)
  .settings(Compile / scalaSource := baseDirectory.value / "cde/src/chipsalliance/rocketchip")
lazy val hardfloat  = (project in file("hardfloat"))
  .settings(commonSettings, chiselSettings)
  .settings(publishArtifact := false)
lazy val `rocket-macros` = (project in file("macros")).settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(publishArtifact := false)
lazy val rocketchip = (project in file("."))
  .settings(commonSettings, chipSettings, chiselSettings)
  .dependsOn(cde)
  .dependsOn(hardfloat)
  .dependsOn(`rocket-macros`)
  .settings( // Assembly settings
    assembly / test := {},
    assembly / assemblyJarName := "rocketchip.jar",
    assembly / assemblyOutputPath := baseDirectory.value / "rocketchip.jar"
  )
  .settings( // Settings for scalafix
    semanticdbEnabled := true,
    semanticdbVersion := scalafixSemanticdb.revision,
    scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-unused"
  )

lazy val addons = settingKey[Seq[String]]("list of addons used for this build")
lazy val make = inputKey[Unit]("trigger backend-specific makefile command")
val setMake = NotSpace ~ ( Space ~> NotSpace )

lazy val chipSettings = Seq(
  addons := {
    val a = sys.env.getOrElse("ROCKETCHIP_ADDONS", "")
    println(s"Using addons: $a")
    a.split(" ")
  },
  unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile ++= addons.value.map(baseDirectory.value / _ / "src/main/scala"),
  mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("rocketchip.Generator"),
  make := {
    val jobs = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors
    val (makeDir, target) = setMake.parsed
    (run in Compile).evaluated
    s"make -C $makeDir  -j $jobs $target".!
  }
)

// mdoc documentation target
lazy val docs = project
  .in(file("docs-target"))
  .dependsOn(rocketchip)
  .enablePlugins(MdocPlugin)
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(
      scalacOptions += "-language:reflectiveCalls",
      mdocIn := file("docs/src"),
      mdocOut := file("docs/generated"),
      mdocExtraArguments := Seq("--cwd", "docs"),
      mdocVariables := Map(
        // build dir for mdoc programs to dump temp files
        "BUILD_DIR" -> "docs-target"
      )
  )
```

and the sbt file of "hardfloat" is:

```
organization := "edu.berkeley.cs"

version := "1.5-SNAPSHOT"

name := "hardfloat"

scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots"),
  Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")
)

addCompilerPlugin("edu.berkeley.cs" % "chisel3-plugin" % "3.5.5" cross CrossVersion.full)
libraryDependencies += "edu.berkeley.cs" %% "chisel3" % "3.5.5"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0" % "test")
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parallel-collections" % "1.0.4"
Test / testForkedParallel := true

publishMavenStyle := true
publishArtifact in Test := false
pomIncludeRepository := { x => false }
// Don't add 'scm' elements if we have a git.remoteRepo definition,
//  but since we don't (with the removal of ghpages), add them in below.
pomExtra := <url>http://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>BSD-style</name>
      <url>http://www.opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/ucb-bar/berkeley-hardfloat.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:github.com/ucb-bar/berkeley-hardfloat.git</connection>
  </scm>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <id>jhauser-ucberkeley</id>
      <name>John Hauser</name>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>aswaterman</id>
      <name>Andrew Waterman</name>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <id>yunsup</id>
      <name>Yunsup Lee</name>
    </developer>
  </developers>

publishTo := {
  val v = version.value
  val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
  if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) {
    Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
  }
  else {
    Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
  }
}
```

I am a newer to the scala sbt project, but I guess the reason for the mistake is the version of chisel3 in the sbt file of hardfloat is 3.5.5, which is different from the other sbt files.

what can I do to overcome this wrong?

Comment: Did you try switching the version of chisel you use in your example project to the one you suspect rocket chip is using? I.e. switch it to `3.5.5`?

Comment: could you edit your post adding the commands you used to build the project and the full error message? [sbt dependencyTree](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/sbt-dependency-tree) can also help you to debug your problem. Feel free to add the output of that tool too